# Xubuntu 18.4 freeze when on youtube and online sudoku

Tags: 18.04

xubuntu 18.4, desktop freezes when on youtube and online suduko game with firefox. i had to cut out power, But could not power on again my pc. I sent my pc to workshop. my power supply was replaced. the PC ran again. But it froze again when on youtube and online sudoku. any idea?

Comment: Please [edit] and add the hardware specifications, especially graphics and drivers (if you installed)?

Comment: hi, the motherboard : MSI G41MP33 COMBO, CPU DUAL CORE E8400, 4G RAM, Geforce GF119.

Comment: For adding information please [edit] the question. Now, the hardware is old so it can be anything, RAM or graphics being the main suspects. The graphics is actually a GeForce 500 series. For this you should have installed the Nvidia 390 driver. Have you?

Comment: Yes, It is aged pc. the workshop found my motherboard did not function well. So it changed to 2nd hand motherboard, MIS 3664h, which originally from HP PRO 3000MT Desktop.

Comment: And my question? Nvidia drivers?

Comment: X.org x server-Nouveau driver

Comment: Please open Software & Updates > Additional Drivers. Then select and install the Nvdia proprietary driver version 390. Reboot and test. If it works fine I can later convert it to an actual answer. If not, then I'm afraid the problem is hardware.

Comment: After click Apply changes, it jumped back to X. org x driver.

Comment: Try in terminal with `sudo apt install nvidia-390` . It'll likely produce some errors. Then select all with mouse, right-click > copy, then [edit] the question and paste it there, as code (click {} and paste inside).

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvida-390

Comment: Do you have internet? It's required for this installation. If you do then try `sudo apt update` first and post the errors if any. If no errors try the previous command again. If it still says not found then, and only then, try `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: yes, it ran well after autoinstall.

Comment: Well, now just reboot and test it for awhile, fingers crossed.

Comment: Below is the tentative answer. If all goes well don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: To keep updated, do I have to run codes every few months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is missing the proper Nvidia drivers for the GeForce 500 series.

Solved by installing the drivers:

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: reboot well, I will try youtube + online sudoku tomorrow

Comment: To keep updated, do I have to run codes every few months?

Comment: No, not this one. But you should keep the system updated. Opening the Updates GUI tool and installing what's offered once a week should be enough.